# Windows application ribbon c# library

Tags: c#, ribbon

Im making an windows desktop application in c# that will contain a ribbon menu like office 2013

Are there a library /dll somewhere that can help me with the ribbon ?
The only ribbon library i found is a 2007/2010 style and that is no good :/

Comment: What UI framework? For WPF I've had good luck with https://github.com/fluentribbon/Fluent.Ribbon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used https://officeribbon.codeplex.com/

1. Load the dll into Visual Studio (Make sure .NET FW 4 is selected)
2. Add the Ribbon dll to your Toolbox in VS (Add Tab, Add Items)
3. Just drag the Ribbon item to your Form

Pretty useful and still continued in development.